# Unity Error "does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInMainScenes'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Team project and someone else did something wrong and now we have this error:

```
Library/PackageCache/com.unity.postprocessing@2.0.3-preview/PostProcessing/Runtime/PostProcessManager.cs(425,66): error CS0117: 'EditorSceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInMainScenes'
```

(we are new in Unity)

we got this kind of error two times.

What I tried:

I tried alredy to remove the Unity paricle pack, but the error is still not solved.

here is a code snipped that comes when I klick on the error:

```
<!-- language: C# -->

            static bool IsVolumeRenderedByCamera(PostProcessVolume volume, Camera camera)
            {
    #if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_EDITOR
                // If the current camera have a custom scene then the camera is rendering that scene,
                // otherwise the camera is rendering the scenes in the SceneManager.
                var customScene = camera.scene;
                return customScene.IsValid()
                    ? UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInScene(volume.gameObject, customScene)
                    : UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInMainScenes(volume.gameObject);
    #else
                return true;
    #endif
```

Comment: According to the documentation those methods do not exist: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.html so it is unclear what you are really trying to do

Comment: Is your Post-Processing package up-to-date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Most Probably Related](https://forum.unity.com/threads/postprocessmanager-error-with-editorscenemanager.673645)

This was solved by simply deleting the `Library` folder (Unity has to closed). The `Library` folder is then rebuild the next time you open the project.

This is probably caused by a **version mismatch** between Unity and the package compiled cache in the `Library`, mostly happens when upgrading to a newer Unity Version but using an outdated package.

Check if there is an **update** for this package (there should be since you seem to use `2.0.3` while there is currently **`2.2.2`** - `2.3.0` in beta) or use a Unity version that is supported by your version of the post-processing package.

---

As this is a team project and also in general: Make sure to **not** include the `Library` folder since it is automatically and constantly updated and recompiled by Unity.

Have a read of [Unsing an external Version Control for Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html) amd as a quickstart use GitHub's [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)

Comment: thank you, I tried it, but after 10sec the error was back.

Comment: @Kristian please make sure the package is up-to-date first. I don't know which Unity Version you are using but in case it is 2019.3.x your post-processing-package is at least 2 minor versions behind

Answer (score 0):

Update post processing package:
Window -> Package Manager -> (Packages: Unity Registry) Post Processing -> Install/Update